# Why is my prepared statement, generated by Spring Data and Hibernate, 'null'?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data, teradata

I am attempting to connect to Teradata using Spring Data JPA, which itself is using Hibernate. I can retrieve objects fine, but I cannot store them.

It seems like my JPA Entity is compatible with the table's schema (because I can retrieve successfully), so I don't think that's the issue, but when I call save, I get an error message that the statement could not be prepared, and that the statement was "null". And it seems like what it means is that the string that represented the statement itself was null, not that there was a null value in it somewhere.

This is what my entity looks like, that I'm trying to save:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class ExampleData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID_FIELD")
    Long id = null;

    @Column(name = "FIELD_A")
    String fieldA = null;

    @Column(name = "FIELD_B")
    String fieldB = null;

    @Column(name = "FIELD_C")
    String fieldC = null;

    // ...getters and setters...
}
```

Note, if it's important, that the table name and the field names are all different in Java as they are in the table.

I'm trying to save the data like so:

```java
ExampleData e = new ExampleData();
e.setFieldA("some data");
e.setFieldB("some more data");
e.setFieldC("hey, some data");

// This is of type ExampleDataRepo
// which is an interface extending CrudRepository<ExampleData, Long>
// with no explicitly defined methods
e = repo.save(e);
```

I'm also using the correct Teradata dialect and driver, set in my application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
```

But, whenever I try to run this, I get an exception with the message `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.08] [Error 1084] [SQLState HY000] Invalid SQL statement: 'null'`, which seems to imply that the SQL statement didn't even attempt to be generated.

Everything I thought I knew about Hibernate and Spring Data/JPA says this should be working. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm facing the same error but with oracle 11g database, and the workaround I found is disabling the Transactions. What spring/hibernate version are you using?